# react server side rendering with client side routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application, isomorphic-javascript

An initial server rendering for my homepage route ( / ) works fine.

Also, subsequent client side navigation to ( /#/page2 ) works fine.

However, if I load /#/page2 directly from the address bar, the server rendered homepage loads in the browser first and then visibly transitions to /#/page2, which is not what I want. I want only /#/page2 to show up without first flashing the homepage.

What's happening is that node is serving up the homepage for the request to /, and then when the response hits the client, the client is running the route handler for /#/page2. Both are behaving correctly. But it's not what I want.

How do I avoid this behavior?

I think what I need is a way to for both the server and client to be aware of the different routes and both be able to handle them (isomorphically), however, the fragment part of the url is not known to the server.

Anyone else have this problem?

This problem isn't react specific. It is specific to SSR to a deep link.

My node router handles "/" as follows

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var React = require('react');
  var Router = require('react-router');
  var Routes = require("../app/clapi-routes.jsx");

  var router = Router.create({location: req.url, routes: Routes});
  router.run(function(Handler, state) {
    var html = React.renderToString(<Handler/>);
    return res.render('index.ejs', {html:html});
  })
});
```

index.ejs is just:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/json-inspector.css"/>
  </head>
<body style="margin:0">
  <%- html %>
  <script src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: will you be able to compose a small jsfiddle/plnkr to illustrate your issue?

Comment: @harshtuna how do I do that for the node server code?

Comment: @JoeHanink http://code.runnable.com/new

Comment: @JoeHanink missed the point it's SSR. Maybe fork this one https://github.com/mhart/react-server-example for demo?

Comment: @jantimon that's cool. if needed I can copy my project over. for now, here's a screen recording of the behavior: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/363598/Vids/clapi-ssr.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop using hash powered navigation. Everything that comes after `#` is client-side only and useless for something like this. So `/#/page2` needs to become `/page2`.

I'm not sure about react, but the same issue exists with other routing systems and there it's really easy to turn off the `#` in urls.

In angular's ui-router is done like this `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Your server-side would need to know to react to all the URLs your client-side knows, but that's how robustness is achieved - doesn't matter how navigation happens (client-side event or link click), both client and server can both handle the scenario end-to-end.

Comment: you are correct. I've posted a complete answer below that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that there are two steps:

**First:** Change the react router to use **Router.HistoryLocation** instead of the default (HashLocation). This makes your routes use html5 push state and changes your route paths from **/#/page2** to **/page2**

```
// in app.jsx (client side routing)

Router.run(AppRoutes, Router.HistoryLocation, function(Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});
```

**Second:** Ensure that your node page routes all return the same "index.ejs". Otherwise your routes, like **/page2** will 404 on a full page refresh (or deeplink)

```
// in server.js (server side routing)

router.get('*', function(req, res) {
  Router.run(Routes, req.path, function(Handler) {
    var html = React.renderToString(<Handler/>);
    return res.render('index.ejs', {html: html});
  });
});
```

**Additionally:** If you are serving **"public" static assets**, declare that before your routes, and remove any **public/index.html** you might have so that your node router handles **/** requests with the server rendered content.